# php session/substr problem

Tags: php, session

I have a strange problem in my code that I really can't explain and it just doesn't make any logical sense to me.  I am setting a session variable called `$_SESSION['user_id']` when a person successfully logs into my website and they are redirected to the `index.php` page.  This works fine and the session works fine, but then once I refresh the page, the value in the session disappears, but I do not see why.

```
$long_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$user_id = substr($long_user_id, 0, -3);
```

Can anyone see what the problem is here?  I thought that the Session variable called `user_id` would remain the same, but for some reason it's empty after a second page-load.

Thanks in advance

Edit:  I didn't post all my code and I made a mistake by not mentioning that I am using `session_start();` on every page.  I would also like to confirm that the code works if I comment out the `substr` part of the code from the page.

Comment: What do you mean by "the value in the session disappears"? Unset? Empty? Changed? Do you have got register_globals=on?

Comment: I mean it disappears in the sense that if I echo the "long_user_id" value there is nothing to display.  The session still exists because if it didn't my code would automatically redirect me to the login page, but it doesn't.  The value just becomes NULL (maybe, I'm not sure!)

Comment: What is your PHP version? Are you making use of `session_register()` or `register_globals`? And can you raise `error_reporting` to the highest level `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);` ?

Comment: I'm using PHP version 5.2.9.  I haven't actively done anything with session_register() or register_globals() as I have created code like this (without the substr) hundreds of times with the exact same settings I have here.  The only difference is the substr part that is causing the session to become empty.  Commenting that line out fixes all problems etc and makes me think it's nothing to do with the session properties

Comment: I've just done something strange.. I changed "$user_id" to a different variable name and when I echoed "$user_id and $new_variable" I got two different values.. the $user_id variable was the same as the SESSION value.  Since when does $user_id have the same value as $_SESSION['user_id']????

Comment: This is why I asked about your code - there might be something interfering with the variables, especially with the scope. Also, you could check out php.ini for an activated session.register_globals - that setting has been deprecated some time ago, but who knows. Did you also try the `error_reporting()` I suggested in the other comment threat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "solution" to this problem makes very little sense.  For some strange reason the $_SESSION['user_id']; was actually being stored as $user_id in the php script.  I cannot explain this and I don't know why it was doing it, but what it meant was that when I adjusted the $user_id variable, it was causing problems with the session and thus making it "disappear" as I stated earlier on.

This issue has been resolved by simply changing the variable names to make sure they do not conflict with the session name.

Answer (score 1):

you always have to start and maintain a session first via [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-start.php) - else your session will disappear. Please note, that you therefore have to call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-start.php) on each and every page.

Comment: I added an "Edit:" to the original post.  I am using session_start().  I didn't think anyone would assume I had forgotten that as this part of the code is the part causing the problem

Comment: There is a session auto start php configuration setting IIRC. If set, you don't have to use `session_start()` anyway.

Comment: Did you activate `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT)`? You may be sending something before session_start() and one single byte will be enough to make problems. Could you paste your code in pastebin? Maybe we spot another problem. Also, check your php.ini for session-related errors as session.autostart and similar problems.

Comment: Nothing is being sent before session_start().  I said the same thing in the other comment, but commenting out the substr line fixes all problems and the session works perfectly.  Having that line of code working is causing all sorts of problems and I can't work out why..

Comment: I can't think of anything either; do you use a specific framework that watches variables and auto-commits changes back into the session?

Comment: No frameworks, nothing, it's just pure PHP.  I'm completely baffled by this problem as it makes no sense what so ever...